# Probability limit of sum of two sequences of random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Say that $a_n$ converges in probability to $0$ but $b_n$ does not have a probability limit. Can we say that $a_n+b_n$ does not converge in probability to $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. If $a_n + b_n \stackrel P\to 0$, what can you say about $(a_n + b_n)-a_n$?